# Delphi. Indy & cyrillic letters

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3, cyrillic

I've been writing some function that downloads source code of specified web page by URL:

```
function GetWebPage(const url: string): tStringList;
var
  idHttp: TidHttp;
begin
  Result := tStringList.Create;
  idHttp := TidHttp.Create(nil);

  // set params
  idHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)';
  idHttp.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'ru en';
  idHttp.Response.KeepAlive := True;
  idHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
  idHttp.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  idHttp.ReadTimeout := 5000;

  try
    try
      Result.values['responce'] := idHttp.Get(url);
    except
      Result.values['responce'] := '';
    end;

  finally
    Result.values['code'] := IntToStr(idHttp.ResponseCode);
    FreeAndNil(idHttp);
  end;
```

I'ts working perfectly with english URL adresses, when I specify a URL like `президент.рф`, iside Indy that URL transforms to `?????????.??` - (screen shot of HTTP Analyzer)

[image]

I've found this solution for my problem:

```
idHttp.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TEncoding.Ansi; 
// also tried - TEncoding.Unicode, TEncoding.UTF8
```

But it not working - when I try to call my function, I get error:

[image]

So, how I can force its function to work with cyrillic adresses?

Thank you.

Comment: Wow, really historical user agent... But anyway, which version of Delphi are you using ? Could you add the proper tag into your question ?

Comment: I am using Delphi XE3 :)

Comment: An Access Violation means you are accessing invalid memory. You are running inside the debugger, so let it show you exactly what code is failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URLs can only contain ASCII characters in them.  You need to pre-format the URL to encode non-ASCII characters before then passing it to `TIdHTTP`.  You can use the `TIdURI.URLEncode()` method for that purpose, eg:

```
Result.values['responce'] := idHttp.Get(TIdURI.URLEncode(url));
```

```
GetWebPage('http://президент.рф');
```

UTF-8 is commonly used for URL encodings, so it is the default encoding used by `TIdURL`, but not all servers use UTF-8, so if you need to use a different encoding then `TIdURI.URLEncode()` has an optional `AByteEncoding` parameter for that purpose.

With that said, international resources are better serviced using [IRIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) instead of URLs, but Indy does not natively support IRIs yet (that will be implemented in Indy 11).

Comment: In what way? You need to be more specific. Did the output in HTTP Analyzer change at all? If not, then the URL's hostname likely needs to be IDN encoded instead. Indy has an `IDNToPunnyCode()` function in the IdIDN.pas unit. Also, I suggest you run the original URL through an actual webbrowser and see how it gets encoded, according to HTTP Analyzer, and then replicate that in Indy.

Comment: Yes, problem is in domains, it need to be a converted. Function `IDNToPunnyCode()` not working, but I found another function for it purpose. So, a `TIdURI.URLEncode()` is only needed to encode url path and parameters. Anyway - thanks for sugeestion. :)

Comment: In what way is `IDNToPunnyCode()` is not working? What are you converting the domain to that is working?

Comment: That means either you are not using Indy on Windows (Indy only implements IDN on Windows right now), or your version of Windows does not support the [`IdnToAscii()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318149.aspx) function.

Comment: On my Win7 x64 system, `IDNToPunnyCode('президент.рф')` does not return an empty string. It returns `xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai` instead.